# Permalink to user profile

Tags: author, permalinks, profiles

How can I retrieve the permalink to a user (author) profile dynamically outside the loop by ID?

an alternative to `the_author_link()`, but for outside the loop.

#### Example:

```
get_author_link($user_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the function you want is [get_author_posts_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url).

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href=<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>">Author Name</a>
```

Comment: An explanation could change this code fragment into an answer.